# if statements in c with NULL

Tags: c, null

I have a program that looks something like this:

```
int someVal = 5;
int startCol = NULL;
int startRow = NULL;
int destCol = NULL;
int destRow = NULL;
for (int i = 0;i<2;i++){
    if (startCol == NULL){
        startCol = someVal;
    }
    // same for other variables
}
```

so basically i want to change the value of the variables at the first time it is being checked but not after.
how can i do that? in python i would use None but it appears i can't use NULL with int. I can't just set the values to 0 because i use them after for array indexes so if the value is 0 i will access the first value but i don't want to.

Comment: NULL evaluates as false.  So does 0

Comment: @Tibrogargan I can't use 0..

Comment: @DarkLeader: my solution would be sort of time consuming and there might be a better solution out there but you could: 
- Set a value that's highly unlikely to happen (don't like this one too much but sometimes it's just enough to make things work)
- Or, you could set all the variable a string, set them to null if they're null then you convert the variables to int passing in the someVal value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL when assigned to the integer converts to zero.

`int` variables do not have any special value which means "not initialized" or "no value".

The only workaround is to choose one integer value which will indicate that variable needs initialization. You can also define more complex data types holding the information about needed initialization

```
typedef struct
{
  bool initialized;
  int val;
}myInt_t;

myInt_t x = {.initialized = false};
if (!x.initilaized) x.val = 100;
```

But the best way is to have correct program algorithm and to program carefully, remembering about not initialized variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using them for indices, setting them to `-1` isn't a bad idea.

Then you will have only to check if they are `-1`.

`NULL` is `((void*)0)`. It is a pointer. Mixing `int` and `pointer` isn't really the best practice but produces the desired output if it is used well.

If you are using the code from the snippet, isn't it an option to just check if `i == 0`?

Comment: well no, the checks above are in a switch case so the index doesn't matter but if a curtain condition is met AND the value of the variable was not changed yet.

Answer (score -1):

`NULL` is for pointers.

`int`s are just int values and not references. You can assign them to `NULL` and test if they are `NULL` but `NULL` is just a number (if used as `int` (I think it is `0`).

If you use it as a pointer, it will point to an address that is not available (dereferenceing it will cause a SEGENV) and you can use it in order to not assign any data with it.